# why casting Base object to derived type reference working?

Tags: c#, casting

AFAIK, casting a base class object to derived type reference throws a run time exception.But in the below class, this works perfectly fine.

```
public class Node<T>
{
        // Private member-variables
        private T data;
        private NodeList<T> neighbors = null;

        public Node() {}
        public Node(T data) : this(data, null) {}
        public Node(T data, NodeList<T> neighbors)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.neighbors = neighbors;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                data = value;
            }
        }

        protected NodeList<T> Neighbors
        {
            get
            {
                return neighbors;
            }
            set
            {
                neighbors = value;
            }
        }
    }
}   

public class BinaryTreeNode<T> : Node<T>
{
    public BinaryTreeNode() : base() {}
    public BinaryTreeNode(T data) : base(data, null) {}
    public BinaryTreeNode(T data, BinaryTreeNode<T> left, BinaryTreeNode<T> right)
    {
        base.Value = data;
        NodeList<T> children = new NodeList<T>(2);
        children[0] = left;
        children[1] = right;

    base.Neighbors = children;
}

public BinaryTreeNode<T> Left
{
    get
    {
        if (base.Neighbors == null)
            return null;
        else
            return (BinaryTreeNode<T>) base.Neighbors[0];
    }
    set
    {
        if (base.Neighbors == null)
            base.Neighbors = new NodeList<T>(2);

        base.Neighbors[0] = value;
    }
}
```

This is the code taken from one of the sample from MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx

as per my understanding, In property **Left**

```
(BinaryTreeNode<T>) base.Neighbors[0]
```

casts the (base) Node to (derived)  BinartTreeNode. How is this working ?

Comment: what does `base.Neighbors[0].GetType().Name` report? You don't show any object creation (no `new Node<>` or `new BinaryTreeNode<>`), so we have **no way of knowing** what the actual objects are here.

Comment: The item in `base.Neighbors[0]` might actually be a `BinaryTreeNode`. Explicit casting allows you to do this, but will throw an exception if the cast fails at runtime. It isn't guaranteed to fail at runtime, which is what you are implying. Alternatively, there could be an explicit cast operator implemented, confusing the situation further.

Comment: It's not working *always*. If the base node is not of that type, you get InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisely because it works, we can conclude that the object in question is actually a `BinaryTreeNode<T>` (or a subclass of that). Objects never change type once created, so somewhere (not shown in your example) you are creating a `BinaryTreeNode<T>`, storing it as  the neighbor (where all we know is that it is a `Node<T>` - which is fine: it is true to say that any `BinaryTreeNode<T>` is a `Node<T>`; class inheritance means "is a"), and then successfully casting it back again. That is legal, but will fail at runtime if the node turns out to **not** be a `BinaryTreeNode<T>`.