# How Interface reference is able to call child class methods?

Tags: c#, oop

How Interface reference is able to call child class methods.

In the below example
How Interface reference can access Test class object?

```
interface ITest
{
  int add();
}

public class Test : ITest
{
  public int add()
  {
    return 1;
  }
  public int sub()
  {
    return -1;
  }
}

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    ITest t = new Test();
    Console.WriteLine((t as Test).sub());
 }
```

### Output

-1.

Comment: It is because of casting `(t as Test)` ? is that what you want to know ?

Comment: Note that your sample does not show parent/child (base/derived) relationship between classes - so while answers are the same code does not match title.

Comment: This is not an unreasonable beginner question, and I don't think the stream of downvotes is warranted.  The OP has created a minimal program that demonstrates behavior that he does not understand.

Comment: @EricJ. - you mean OP needs something like this [why casting Base object to derived type reference working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686352/why-casting-base-object-to-derived-type-reference-working)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Assuming he realizes that he can substitute the base class in that answer for the interface in his question.  This is a beginner's question, so not sure if that leap is too much for this particular OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `t` actually IS an instance of `Test` class. Storing it into interface does not limit it to interface methods only (if used as interface, then yes, is typecasted to `Test`, then no).
Similar for example:

```
IEnumerable<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("MyName"); // --> This won't compile since IEnumerable does not have Add method
(list as List<string>).Add("MyName"); // --> This will compile and execute, since underlying Type actually IS List<string>
```

<strike>But many times when we are using interfaces we do not know actuall underlying type, so thats why this type of casting is not so common. I think its also considered bad practice, but I'm not sure of that.</strike>
As Eric pointed out, we should not be making such kind of casting. It means there's a problem with our design and we should consider to redesign.

Comment: Usually when using an interface, we *should not be* concerned with the underlying type.  That is usually a clue that we have a design problem.

Comment: Yes, I meant that, just wrote it in some awkward words. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 5):

This line

> Console.WriteLine((t as Test).sub());

casts whatever is aliased by `t` to type `Test`.

You know that `t` is convertible to `Test` because you assigned an instance of `Test` to it

```
ITest t = new Test();
```

Note that if the type of `t` were not convertible to `Test`,

```
t as Test
```

will evaluate to null, and the subsequent call to .sub() will result in a NullReferenceException.

Although it is seldom a good design choice, you could do something like

```
if (t is Test)
{
   Console.WriteLine(((Test)t).sub());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("t cannot be converted to type Test");
}
```

or alternatively

```
Test myTest = t as Test;
if (myTest != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(myTest.sub());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("t cannot be converted to type Test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `sub()` method, from the test class, therefore, you get the result of `-1`. Please specify the example code of the problem you have, and what you were planning to recieve.